# Enzyme: When to use shallow, render, or mount?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

From the [Enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme) docs [shallow](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md), [render](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/render.md), and [mount](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md) are described, but when to use which method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should you use render and shallow in Enzyme / React tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710309/when-should-you-use-render-and-shallow-in-enzyme-react-tests)

Answer (score 33):

#### shallow

- No children rendering
- Isolated, you know for sure the error comes from here

#### render

- No lifecycles
- Render children
- Less APIs (`setState`, `debug`...)

#### mount

Will require jsdom or similar.

- Lifecycle methods, like `componentDidMount`
- Render children

---

If some of your children are connected components, you probably don't want to use `mount`, or you will need to setup a `<Provider>` and store creation, which would be a bit painful, just use `shallow` in this case.

This [post](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/465#issuecomment-227697726) is really insightful about the subject.

Comment: OK, what about props and state?

Comment: Works the same, you can use `setState` and `setProps`

Comment: What if you have a property referencing some callback function?

Comment: Works the same ;)