# Test conditionally rendered child Component using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I need to write a test to test if the corresponding child component is rendered or not based on a prop.

To do that, I've got a component which has a child component rendered on a certain condition. Other child components are rendered without any conditional check.

To do that, in my parent component, I am receiving a prop 'renderChild'.

If 'renderChild' is true, then render the child component.

For e.g., in my ReactJS, in the ParentComponent :

```
return {
    <div>
    { props.renderChild && <ChildComponent {...childProps} /> }
        <ChildComponent2 {...childProps2 } />
    </div>
}
```

Now, here's the test I've written :

```
const parentProps = {
    renderChild: true;
    name: "parent",
    message: "Hello Parent"
};

const childProps = {
  name: "child1",
  message: "Hello child1"   
};


test('childComponent should be rendered if renderChild is true', () => {
    const childComponent = shallow(<ChildComponent {...childProps} />);
    expect(childComponent).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Could you please help me achieve this?

Comment: You should be snapshoting your parent component right ?

Comment: yes, that I'm doing that anyhow in a seperate test method. But how, how I compare? Sorry, but am new to this framework!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should you use render and shallow in Enzyme / React tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710309/when-should-you-use-render-and-shallow-in-enzyme-react-tests)

Comment: I think your problem is in the use of `shallow`, please look at the above and let me know if it helps. I know that you are learning so I thought it would be helpful to you as well

Comment: Thanks a lot! it helped :)