# the shallow and mount in enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Below is the component Calculator.

```
import SubComponent from './SubComponent';
export default class Calculator extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      result,
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="number"
          defaultValue={0}
          ref={(el) => this.elements.value1 = el}
        />
        <input
          type="number"
          defaultValue={0}
          ref={(el) => this.elements.value2 = el}
        />
        <button type="button" onClick={this.add} />
        <p className="result">{result}</p>
        <SubComponent name="sub component"></SubComponent>
      </form>
    );
  }


}
```

And below is the SubComponent.

```
import React from 'react';
import SubSubComponent from './SubSubComponent ';

const SubComponent = ({ name }) => (
  <div>
    {`${name}`}
    <SubSubComponent name="sub sub component"  />
  </div>
);

export default SubComponent;
```

And below is the subsubcomponent referenced by subcomponent.

```
import React from 'react';
import SubSubComponent from './SubSubComponent ';

const SubComponent = ({ name }) => (
  <div>
    {`${name}`}
    <SubSubComponent name="sub sub component"  />
  </div>
);

export default SubComponent;
```

When I tested the shallow and mount method provided by enzyme like below.

```
const calculator = shallow(
  <Calculator />
);
console.log(calculator.html());

const calculator2 = mount(
  <Calculator />
);
console.log(calculator2.html());
```

They both print below html.

```
<form><input type="number" value="0"><input type="number" value="0"><button type="button"></button>
  <p class="result"></p>
  <div>sub component<div>sub sub component</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

But the shallow render in the doc said 'Shallow rendering is useful to constrain yourself to testing a component as a unit, and to ensure that your tests aren't indirectly asserting on behavior of child components.'

So I thought the shallow does not render the child component. 
Could you please explain the differences between the two method? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `html` function returns the entire markup, including sub-components. It treats shallow and deep mounted components the same, fully rendering the tree.

See the docs [here](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/html.html).

If you show the output of shallow a different way, it should show the shallow output. For example:

`expect(calculator).toEqual(...);`

or

`expect(wrapper.find(SubComponent).length).toBe(1);`

Shallow mounting (without use of `html`) renders a component `<SubComponent />` as `<SubComponent />` whereas deep mounting would render the contents of the sub-component. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38747914/7470360) for a more detailed explanation of shallow vs deep mounting.