# What is the difference between shallow & render in jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

In jest, what is the difference between using shallow & render from enzyme?

Here is an example of both:

Test rendering with shallow:

```
import "jest";
import * as React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Item from "../item.component";

describe("Item", () => {
  it("renders correct", () => {
    const item = {
        name: "A"
      };

    const component = shallow(
      <Item item={item}/>
    );

    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Test rendering with render

```
import "jest";
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "enzyme";
import Item from "../item.component";

describe("Item", () => {
  it("renders correct", () => {
    const item = {
        name: "A"
      };

    const component = render(
      <Item item={item}/>
    );

    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

What are the typical usage of these 2. I wrote all my tests with shallow, should I go back and change that to render in some cases?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710309/when-should-you-use-render-and-shallow-in-enzyme-react-tests

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`shallow` and `render` are specific to Enzyme, which can be used independently of Jest.

`shallow` renders only the top-level component and doesn't require a DOM. It is intended for isolated unit tests.

`render` renders the entire component and wraps it with Cheerio, which is a jQuery implementation for Node.js. It is intended for blackbox integration/e2e tests with the aid of jQuery-like selectors. It may have its uses but `shallow` and `mount` are commonly used.

Neither of them is supposed to be used with `toMatchSnapshot`, at least not without additional tools (`enzyme-to-json` for `shallow` and `mount`).