# Can I, (and should I), make assertions about what HTML elements a component renders using Enzyme's shallow()?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jsdom

**The question:**

I am writing a unit test for a React component called `<BaseEdit />`. In order to test that the component works, I want to assert that it will render an HTML element `<input/>`, and I want to do so using shallow() instead of mount().

The following test case works:

```
const baseEditWrapper = mount(<BaseEdit />)
const inputElement = baseEditWrapper.find('input')
assert(inputElement.exists())
assert.strictEqual(inputElement.prop('type'), 'text')
```

However, if I change `mount()` to `shallow()`, then the test fails. It fails because `baseEditWrapper.find('input')` returns an empty/stub/nonexistant ShallowWrapper object.

---

**The Underlying HTML:**

The `<BaseEdit />` component, when mounted using Enzyme and JSDom, creates the following DOM elements.

```
<div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root WithStyles(ForwardRef(TextField))-root-27 WithStyles(ForwardRef(TextField))-root-96" style="width:120px">
  <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInput-underline MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInput-formControl">
    <input type="text" aria-invalid="false" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Extra Details:**

The documentation for shallow() is [here](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/shallow.html).

The question, [when should you use render and shallow in enzyme react tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710309/when-should-you-use-render-and-shallow-in-enzyme-react-tests), shows that finding by selectors is supported when using shallow().

The test case below proves that shallow does rendering multiple layers of HTML elements, and acts as a work around solution for my question.

```
const shallowWrapper = shallow(<BaseEdit />)
assert(shallowWrapper.html().includes('<input')
assert(shallowWrapper.html().includes('type=\"text\"'))
```

Such a solution seems hacky, however, and I would rather keep my solution in line with the use of Enzyme's `ShallowWrapper` interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `.dive()` to find the input:

```js
const input = wrapper.find(TextField).dive().find('input')
```

You might even need to dive more than once, if the `input` is nested inside multiple React components:

```js
// This is a little contrived, but something like this:
const InnerTextField = () => <input />;
const TextField = () => <InnerTextField />;
const BaseEdit = () => <TextField />;

// You would need to do this to find the input:
const input = wrapper.find(TextField).dive().dive().find('input');
```

You also asked if you *should* use `shallow`:

If you want to make assertions on the underlying HTML (for example, you want to make sure `BaseEdit` always renders an `input`), you're probably better off using `mount`, unless there's a reason not to.

`shallow` is useful when you want to test a single layer of your component tree. It looks like you're using Material UI, so a possible test might be to check that `BaseEdit` is passing props correctly to `TextField`.

```js
it('passes the required prop to the underlying component', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<BaseEdit required />);
  expect(wrapper.find(TextEdit).props().required).toBe(true);
  wrapper.setProps({ required: false });
  expect(wrapper.find(TextEdit).props().required).toBe(false);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Using dive() felt more rigid than checking HTML, so I decided to just go with mount() for everything. The biggest reason why is that mount() vs shallow() makes a difference on the scale of milliseconds, while running the whole suite of mocha tests, (which includes the process of loading node and then loading all modules), takes minutes. I found these two articles interesting for exploring the debate between shallow() and mount():
https://kentcdodds.com/blog/why-i-never-use-shallow-rendering , 
https://hackernoon.com/why-i-always-use-shallow-rendering-a3a50da60942

Comment: Sound good! There’s a lot of debate about shallow vs mount, IMO they both have their uses, just for different types of testing. Glad I could help!