# Enzyme: shallow render a component which requires a very specific child type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme, preact

Imagine you have the following two components

```
class Parent ... {    
    
    render() {
        let child;
        if(this.props.children[0].type.IS_CHILD){ 
            this.props.children[0].isInsideParent = true;
            child = this.props.children[0];
            return <div>{child}</div>
        }
        return <div>ERROR</div>
    }
}

class Child ... {
    
    public static IS_CHILD = true;
   
    render() {
        let parent;
        if(this.props.isInsideParent) 
            return <div>OK</div>;
        return <div>ERROR</div>
    }
}
```

If you try to test using enzyme as follow:

```
const wrapper1 = shallow(<Parent><Child></Child></Parent>)
const wrapper2 = shallow(<Parent><Child></Child></Parent>).dive();
const wrapper3 = mount(<Parent><Child></Child></Parent>)
```

It will work only with `mount` because it's the only one rendering the inner component as well (therefore children[0].type is defined as class Child, so it has an IS_CHILD property).

Instead, with shallow, it tries to render the Parent component, but when it tries to see if it internally has a Child element, it won't see it (children[0].type would be equal to function ShallowRenderStub(_a))

Is there a way to just test this very specific case with enzyme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent logic relies on rendering a specific child component. And you got your answer yourself - you should use `mount` since it renders the *children* components.

> The difference between shallow() and mount() is that shallow() tests components in isolation from the child components they render, while mount()goes deeper and tests a component's children.

Source: [When should you use render and shallow in Enzyme / React tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710309/when-should-you-use-render-and-shallow-in-enzyme-react-tests)